# How Do I See The Most Common Values In A List?

Tags: c#

I have a list with a shed load of data points and a lot of them are the same as each other. Is there a convenient command to sort the list to see what occurs the most?

I'm writing the results to a text file, so I can actually see the results of the list?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Can you give an example of your list? a lambda expression is probably useful here?

Comment: convenience is really personal thing, however, what have you got so far?

Comment: `var result = MyList.GroupBy(item => item).OrderByDescending(chunk => chunk.Count()).First();`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko nice

Comment: I have tried stuff, but its really come out to a group of clunky for loops, and since my data is pretty large, I'm reluctant to use it as a good solution. I do not know how to do lambdas in c# and don't really know too much about them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class SomeObject
        {
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
        }

        private static void ListCount()
        {
            var items = new List<SomeObject>
            {
                new SomeObject {FirstName = "santa", LastName = "claus"},
                new SomeObject {FirstName = "fred", LastName = "claus"},
                new SomeObject {FirstName = "tooth", LastName = "fairy"},
                new SomeObject {FirstName = "easter", LastName = "bunny"},
            };

            var byLastNameFrequency = items.GroupBy(i => i.LastName).OrderByDescending(g => g.Count()).ThenBy(g => g.Key);
            foreach (var name in byLastNameFrequency)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(name.Key + ", " + name.Count());
            }
        }
```